# Execution of a program called by a shell called by crontab returns code 127

Tags: scripting, cron, ksh, aix, executable

I'm stuck with the following (simple) problem :
I want a script to be executed every 10 minutes. This script calls executable files. I use crontab and ksh on a AIX 5.3 system.

The script makes use of relative paths, but changing the executable path to absolute didn't make any difference. So, after a few tries and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899737/crontab-run-in-directory), I came up with the following crontab entry (*/10 doesn't work)

```
rs14:/home/viloin# crontab -l
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * cd /home/viloin/cardme/bin && /bin/ksh myScript.ksh
```

here is the script :

```
#!/bin/ksh

Main(){
  printf "executed in : %s\n" $(pwd);
  executableFile 2>/dev/null 1>&2;
  exeResult=$?; # expected return value : 90
  printf "%s\n" $exeResult;
}

Main;
```

Here is the output when I run the command manually :

```
rs14:/home/viloin/cardme/bin# cd /home/viloin/cardme/bin && /bin/ksh myScript.ksh
executed in : /home/viloin/cardme/bin
90
```

And finally the output when crontab runs it for me (from mail) :

```
 Subject: Output from cron job cd /home/viloin/cardme/bin && /bin/ksh myScript.ksh, viloin@rs14.saprr.local, exit status 0

Cron Environment:
 SHELL = /usr/bin/sh
 PATH=/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/java14/jre/bin:/usr/java14/bin
 CRONDIR=/var/spool/cron/crontabs
 ATDIR=/var/spool/cron/atjobs
 LOGNAME=viloin
 HOME=/home/viloin

Your "cron" job executed on rs14.saprr.local on Wed Aug 24 11:50:00 CEST 2016
cd /home/viloin/cardme/bin && /bin/ksh myScript.ksh


produced the following output:

executed in : /home/viloin/cardme/bin
127


*************************************************
Cron: The previous message is the standard output
      and standard error of one of your cron commands.
```

My file myScript.ksh has all rights :

```
rs14:/home/viloin/cardme/bin# ll -al myScript.ksh
-rwxrwxrwx    1 viloin   cardme          174 Aug 24 10:54 myScript.ksh
```

To make sure that my executableFile is not really exiting with code 127, I used the echo binaries, renamed it and I have the same behavior (Except that it returns 0 instead of 90 when I run the command manually).

What is causing this difference between manually typing the command and asking crontab to do it for me ?

Comment: Often, it's `PATH`. What happens if you run `env -i myScript.ksh` manually?

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz It shows the correct output, no 127 exit code.

Comment: Is your `executableFile` something that might reasonably expect to be run interactively and would fail if it's not connected to a terminal?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but i did cp /bin/echo ./executableFile to make sure the program is not returning 127 for any reason. So my executable is echo, nothing more, and calling echo; should return 0

Comment: change your shell script to provide a full or relative path to the executable: `./executableFile ...` -- in interactive use, you either have `.` or the cardme/bin/directory in your PATH: that will not be true in cron's environment.

Comment: Note that 127 is the bash exit status for command not found: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Exit-Status

Comment: @glennjackman I do have . in my PATH. So changing my script to ./executableFile fixed my issue ! So simple thanks a lot. Post this as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your shell script to provide a full or relative path to the executable:

```
./executableFile ...
```

In interactive use, you must either have `.` or the `cardme/bin` directory in your PATH: that will not be true in cron's environment.

Comment: Thanks again. My executableFile (the original one) used PATH variables, so I changed my crontab entry to 
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * . $HOME/.profile && cd /home/viloin/cardme/bin && /bin/ksh myScript.ksh
This change fixed the previous issue too since my PATH is now correct for cron

Comment: Good job. cron problems almost always are environment-related.

Comment: you might be able to use `*/10` instead of `0,10,20,30,40,50` -- check your `crontab(5)` man page.

Comment: I can't see any reference to this notation in my man page, and editing crontab accordingly gives me the following error : crontab: error on previous line; unexpected character found in line.
It looks like the AIX 5.3 implementation doesn't allow this notation.

Comment: oh, I didn't notice your [tag:aix] tag